# yii2 separate module authentication

Tags: php, yii2

i have 2 modules in yii2 and I wish to allow users to login to these modules using a different IdentityClass per module.

The problem is that when the user logs into module A he is automatically logged in module B too! Is this a configuration issue? I am guessing that the user component will need to be configured per module, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Throw exception on module init (or create user redirect to login page).

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        if(Yii::$app->userForSecondModule->isGuest) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not logging in');
        }

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

also you can use user from module settings

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config/main.php'));

        if(Yii::$app->getModule('module')->userForSecondModule->isGuest) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not logging in');
        }

        // custom initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a separate user component from the module configuration but still the user appears as logged in to the other module too